# Get row's column value after I find the correct row with max

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL2Jl.png)

My goal is to find the code value in the row, that has the highest absolute value in the amt column while cosidering that I am only searching for max absolute between those rows, that have the same pair of id and id_addl.

For example - the first 3 rows have matching id + id_addl combinations, so I find the highest absolute (this case it's 43562). Now I need to find that row's code, which would be CLP.

Here is what I have:

```
with max_code as(
  select
    s.id,
    s.id_addl,
    s.amt,
    s.code
  from
    schema.viw s
)
select
  b.code,
  b.amt,
  b.id,
  b.id_addl,
  b.max_amt,
  m.code
from
  (
    select
      a.code,
      a.amt,
      a.id,
      a.id_addl,
      max(abs(a.amt))over(partition by a.id, a.id_addl) max_amt
    from
      schema.viw a
  ) b,
  max_code m
where
    b.id = m.id and
  b.id_addl = m.id_addl and
  b.max_amt = m.amt;
```

Any idea how I can improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAX(...) KEEP (...) OVER (...)`:

```
SELECT code,
       amt,
       id,
       id_addl,
       MAX(ABS(amt))
         OVER (PARTITION BY id, id_addl) AS max_amt,
       MAX(code)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ABS(amt))
         OVER (PARTITION BY id, id_addl)
         AS max_code
FROM  schema.viw;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schema.viw (id, id_addl, amt, code) AS
SELECT 1, 4132, 23432, 'USD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4132, 12354, 'EUR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4132, 43562, 'CLP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3124, 84563, 'EUR' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CODE | AMT | ID | ID_ADDL | MAX_AMT | MAX_CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | USD | 23432 | 1 | 4132 | 43562 | CLP |
> | EUR | 12354 | 1 | 4132 | 43562 | CLP |
> | CLP | 43562 | 1 | 4132 | 43562 | CLP |
> | EUR | 84563 | 2 | 3124 | 84563 | EUR |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=133fed3eee69aa7eebd05a1e3af3886b)*